# Not getting expected result from RxJS map() operator with Angular HttpClient

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I am trying to understand the `map()` operator of RxJS.

Below is one of the example with works as expected. In this example all names will be appended with text student one by one.

```
studentArray:string[]=['sam','robert','lisa'];
from(this.studentArray).pipe(map((s:string)=>s=s+' student')).subscribe(d=>console.log(d));
```

Now I have below sample code. With this code I am calling a service which returns array of ToDo objects. What I am trying to do is the iterate each ToDo object and return the updated object

[image]

But when I do so it gives an error and reason for the error is `data` variable in the `map` operator. With above example map operator is not getting single element of an array of ToDo but the entire array is being passed to the map.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Edit: Updated image.

Comment: the map should probably be something like `.pipe(map(data => data.title + 'append')).subscribe(...)`  without the assignment.  Also the `map` pipe is going to give your an array.  If you want to map the array items you have to do `.pipe(map(data => data.map(item => ....)))` inside the map pipe.

Comment: @JasonWhite The question here I is string array is functionating differently than an array of custom object. See my string example. I would like to do the same with custom array object.

Comment: Tip: inline code formatting (`like this`) only needs single backticks. A "code fence" of three backticks is only needed for block formatting.

Answer (score 2):

`map()` function that you use is not JavaScript standard [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), it is the `RxJs` [map](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) operator, it applies a project function to each value emitted (in your case, a single value is an array of `ToDo`) by the source Observable, and emits the resulting values as an Observable.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.  But in that theory when I use the same RxJS map operator with string array its works fine. See my example in the question.

Comment: In the string array example, you use `from` operator that emits the items of that array, and then the `map` operator concatenate ' student' for each item emitted. 
https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/from

Answer (score 1):

It is not Angular-ish thing per say but it is more a Typescript compiler issue. It is doing its job correctly telling you that you are assigning something of `type B` to something else of `type C`. In our case here, it is the fact that you are assigning a string to an array of TODOs.

What `@Jason White` mentioning in the comment is IMO the correct answer to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `map` operator incorrectly. The `map` operator receives a value, transforms it, and returns the transformed value. You are doing an assignment instead. A valid example would be:

```
.pipe(
   map((value: string) => value + 'append')
)
```

Also, your `data` is not a single `ToDo` but an array, i.e. `ToDo[]`. So with `data = data.title + 'append'` you are trying to assign a `string` to a `ToDo[]`.

If I understand correctly, you want to append something on each `ToDo`'s `title`  property. Then you would have to do something like this:

```
this.http.get<ToDo[]>('YOU-ENDPOINT-URL-HERE').pipe(
   concatMap((dataArray: ToDo[]) => from(dataArray)), // from array to single objects
   map((data: ToDo) => {
      data.title += 'append'; // transform tittle
      return data; // return transformed data
   }),
   toArray() // recreate array
).subscribe((d) => console.log(d));
```

**EDIT:**
Your first example is not equivalent to your use-case. The `from` operator takes an array, in your example `string[]`, and converts it into an `Observable<string>`.

The `http.get<Todo[]>` declares that the returned type from your backend is going to be an array. And this is the type of data that will be passed to your pipe, hence to your `map` operator as well.

Comment: Updated screenshot. Yes I would like to update the title for every custom object in the array. The question here is why the data being passed to map is an array. See my similar type of example in the question. Which works fine with map but when I try to do the same with custom object array it doesn't work.

Comment: @RaviKhambhati See my EDIT section. On another note, you are using the `map` operator incorrectly in your updated screenshot as well. Please re-read my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Follow `@Vasileios Kagklis`'s answer.  He explains your issue.  The rxjs `map` pipe is completely different than the JavaScript higher order `map` function.  You shouldn't be assigning a value in the `map` pipe with `=`.

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to accomplish with this but from what I can understand you might be looking for something like...

```js
this.http.get<ToDo[]>(`....`)
  .pipe(
    map(data => data.map(todo => ({
       ...todo,
       title: todo.title + 'append'
     })
  )
  .susbscribe(todos => console.log(todos));
```

So the `map` rxjs pipe, receives a `ToDo[]`, so `data` is a `ToDo[]` not a single `ToDo`.  So once the data is emitted you have to iterate over that array and mutate each item in the array (JavaScript's higher order `map` function) updating the title.